# Is "It's got better now" grammatical?

Tags: grammar, colloquial-language

sentence: "It wasn't going well at first, but **it's got better now"**

Something feels wrong with it, but it's like, I've heard people use it or something like it before, so I'm not sure if it's grammatically okay or not.

Feels like it should be *"It's **gotten** better now"* or *"It's **getting** better now*, but I don't understand why that is.

corrected the original sentence from "It wasn't going well at first, but **it got better now.**" to "It wasn't going well at first, but **it's got better now.**" (It was a typo)

Comment: Note that your suggested alternative *It's gotten better now* is a shortened version of *It **has** gotten better now*. Many Americans make some subtle distinction between ***got*** and ***gotten*** (to do with *ownership*, I think), but I don't know how that relates to the example here. But as a Brit, I'd probably just say *It's better now* (where ***'s = is***).

Comment: @FumbleFingers I speak American English, and I'd say, "I've got two cars," but I wouldn't say "I've gotten two cars." Is that what you mean?

Comment: I've got two cars means I have two cars, in BrE and AmE. The verb **have** has two forms in the present tense in English.  There is nothing wrong in saying in AmE: I've gotten two cars. That is correct. Where got means buy, for instance. Or even: to receive as a gift. The Brits would say there: I've got two cars. And only context will tell you it the speaker means: simple present of have or present perfect of get. Tricky, huh?

Comment: The distinction I see:  The "gotten" participle is used with the *copular, dynamic* sense of "to get", as in "I've gotten better".  The "got" participle is used with the *transitive, stative* sense of "to get", as in "I've got a lovely bunch of coconuts".  The form "I've got better" does *not* mean that I'm in better shape -- it means that I obtained and still retain some (direct) object that is better.

Comment: @GaryBotnovcan Before one gets into that sort of explanation, one needs to point out the principal parts of the verb get. British and American English here are not the same, though the idiom is: a situation is said to get better in both. But: get/got/gotten=AmE; get/got/got=BrE.

Comment: Perhaps I should be clear, @Lambie.  The distinction I describe is the one that, as a native speaker of my dialect, explains my instinctive choice.    I can't explain the British oddities but I am a product of the American.  AmE; get/got/(gotten/got) -- distinct strong and weak participle forms, which depend on the type of argument licensed.

Comment: @GaryBotnovcan The main point here is that: ***it got better*** is simple past, in British and American English. Therefore, ***it got better now*** is not grammatical. **It got better yesterday or last week or two hours ago** would be grammatical.

Comment: Although we can argue whether "it got better recently" or "it got better by now" are examples of better *style*, they all have sufficiently similar *grammar*.  On my side of the pond, there's nothing all that remarkable about "it got better now".

Comment: I'm a dyed-in-the-wool AmE speaker, and it's now about being remarkable. It's just basic standard AmE grammar: "It's gotten better recently". versus: "It got better yesterday". Now, colloquial AmE uses lately with got, but it is not standard.

Comment: ***Now the question has been changed***: "It's got better now" is correct in British English. In American English it would be: "It's gotten better now". Please note: you should make the change in the question header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your intuition is correct. The sentence “It got better now”  is incorrect, and the other two are correct.

**Simple Past**

The reason the first sentence is incorrect is that it is in the simple past, which is incompatible with the word *now*. You wouldn’t say “It got better now” any more than you would say “I went to the store now.”

It got better in the past, but it may or may not be better right now.

**Present Pefect and Present Continuous**

Your other sentences are correct because they’re in the present perfect and present continuous, respectively.

The present perfect means that it got better at some point in the past, but more importantly it’s still better right now.

The present continuous means that it’s still in the process of getting better. It may not be completely better yet.

In either of these cases, the sentence is still making a comment on the present state of things, so “now” is appropriate.

Comment: As always, I'd appreciate an explanation for the downvote. Maybe I can improve the answer? Thanks!

Comment: I don't thing you explain what is really going on. Sorry. You say one is wrong and two are right and do not explain the mechanisms, nor the tenses, nor the difference between AmE and BrE with get.

Comment: @Lambie Not that I don't appreciate you trying to help, but his or her answer was more digestible and clearer. Sorry. But your answer just confused me.

Comment: @strawberries Many do not understand the difference between the BrE and AmE usage here of the verb get. Now you have changed your question: ***It's got better now*** is correct in British English.

Answer (score 2):

"It wasn't going well at first, but it got better now"

Correction for both BrE and AmE:
"It wasn't going well at first, but it's got better now" [BrE]

"It wasn't going well at first, but it's gotten better now" [AmE]

I**n BrE, the present perfect of to get** [adjective] = **has/have + got [adjective]**.  get/got/got

In AmE, the present perfect of to get [adjective]= has gotten [adjective].
**In fact, the PP of get is gotten**.
get/got/gotten

**British English no longer uses gotten as the past participle of get**.

"It wasn't going well at first, but it's **getting** better now"

present continuous-
That sentence is fine in BrE or AmE English. There is no difference.

"It wasn't going well at first, but it **got** better yesterday."
That one also is fine in both. It is simple past.

Comment: Interesting distinction between AmE/BrE. I wasn't aware. :-) By the way, as @FumbleFingers pointed out, there seems to be an exception for statements of ownership, e.g. "I've got two cars" [AmE].

Comment: I have no idea what was meant. In AmE and in BrE there are two ways to express owning (having something) and I believe I explained it pretty straightforwardly. Unless one has been on the front trenches of teaching English, generally, one doesn't necessarily have this at the front of one's mind.